# Складність — трудність

Tags: синоніми

Чи можна вважати іменники **складність** та **трудність** повними синонімами?

Академічний тлумачний словник пояснює [складний](http://sum.in.ua/s/skladnyj) як *важкий для розуміння, вирішення, здійснення*, а [трудний](http://sum.in.ua/s/trudnyj) — *який вимагає багато праці, великих зусиль, напруження для виконання, здійснення, подолання, опанування, втілення й т. ін.*

Як тоді краще сказати: це завдання викликало *складність* чи *трудність* у виконанні?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## «Викликати»?

По-перше, мені, якщо чесно, взагалі ріже слух словосполучення «викликати складність/трудність». Як це — *викликати* складність/трудність, звідки і навіщо їх кличуть? Мені видається не дуже вдалою калькою з російської «вызвало сложности/трудности».

«Словник української мови» в 20 томах надає [такі тлумачення слова «викликати»](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=9069&page=321), що в переказі моїми словами зводяться до:

1. В прямому сенсі кликати когось (людину, тварину); або просто голосно щось вигукувати («викликати пісню»).
2. Спонукати когось до змагання/двобою/тощо («викликаю на бій»).
3. Спричиняти якусь реакцію («викликало втому, критику, обурення, розмову»).

Але складнощі/труднощі (в завданні) — це *не реакція*. Вони (складнощі/труднощі) властиві самому завданню — або принаймні сполученню цього завдання з певним виконавцем і певними умовами. Тому на мою думку слово «викликати» тут не зовсім доречне.

Що може бути:

- Завдання може *виявитися складним/трудним*.
- Або *виконання* якогось завдання може бути *пов'язане з (певними) складнощами/труднощами*.
- Або *під час виконання* якогось завдання можуть *виникнути складнощі/труднощі*.
- Або *проблеми/складнощі/труднощі під час виконання якогось завдання (чи сам факт призначення якогось завдання)* можуть (може) *викликати проблеми/складнощі/труднощі у виконанні наступного (чи більш загального) завдання*;
- Або *умови/обставини* можуть *викликати складнощі/труднощі при виконанні певного завдання*.
- Тощо (але не саме завдання викликає складність/трудність у самому собі).

NB: Словники можуть не містити всіх значень. Тож я можу помилятися (неповнота словника разом з тим фактом, що в моєму оточенні так не кажуть, могла *викликати* в мене хибні висновки). Але мені така фраза ріже вухо.

## «Складний» vs. «трудний»

«Складний» і «трудний» мають різну етимологію.

- «трудний» — це той, для якого треба вкласти багато труда (праці);
- «складний» — це той, що складається з багатьох (чи принаймні декількох) частин.

Але на практиці, якщо брати в сполученні з іменниками «завдання»/«задача», різниця, мені здається, вже майже стерлася.

Хіба що, може, «складний» може трішки більше акцентувати увагу на об'єктивній складності (що не залежить від виконавця), а «трудний» — на потугах, необхідних від конкретного виконавця для завершення.

(Або «трудний» трішечки більше акцентує увагу на вкладанні труда, а «складний» — на всій множині можливих проблем (психологічна важкість, наявність навичок тощо). Мовляв, пройти скрізь двір із собаками людині з кінофобією — радше важко/складно, ніж трудно; або спроектувати літак людині без відповідних навичок — радше неможливо/складно, ніж трудно. Але останнє — я не впевнений, що то все ще реальні відтінки слів, а не моя уява.)

Comment: Ё шче діёслово [виникати](http://sum.in.ua/s/vynykaty). Цебто _при виконаннї вправи **виника́ли** складношчі_.